# Add labels to bar chart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to add labels to a bar graph and omit 0's. Right now it's a mess to read. I would also like the labels to appear over the bars and have the labels positioned either on or above the bars. I've been able to adjust the label heights but as I'm plotting a ratio the scale on the y axis could vary which is a challenge. This is the graph so far

```
A <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
HQ <- c(0,0,0.2,0,0.5)
Category <-c(1,2,1,1,2)
HIData <-data.frame(A,HQ,Category)

Ainorder<- c('B','C','D','A','E')
Listofcolors <- c("A"="red","B"="red","C"="blue","D"="red","E"="blue")
HIPlot <- ggplot(data=HIData, aes(x=factor(A,level=Ainorder),y=HQ))+ geom_col()
HIPlot <- HIPlot + theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
HIPlot <- HIPlot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5, color = Listofcolors),axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0,vjust=0.5,color = "black")) 
HIPlot <- HIPlot + ylab("HQ")+xlab("")+ labs(title=paste0(first("HQ for "),HIData$ID))
HIPlot <- HIPlot + aes(fill=Category)
HIPlot <- HIPlot + geom_text(data=HIData, aes(label=HQ), angle=90) 
HIPlot
```

[image: This shows what it currently looks like]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Probably: `geom_text(data=HIData, aes(label=HQ), angle=90, data=function(x) subset(x, HQ>0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the text show up only on >0, we can subset the data for that layer. To make it show up cleanly above the bars, we can use hjust (the alignment is calculated before the angle rotation, so up-down here is driven by hjust). To make room for those labels, we can adjust the y scale to put more padding on the top (15% here, instead of 5% default).

```
HIData$A = factor(HIData$A, level = Ainorder)

ggplot(data=HIData, aes(x=A, y=HQ, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(data=subset(HIData, HQ > 0), aes(label=HQ), angle=90, hjust = -0.2) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.15))) +
  
  labs(title=paste0("HQ for ID TBD"), y = "HQ", x = NULL) +
  
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5, color = Listofcolors),
        axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0,vjust=0.5,color = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that is correct. I was trying to recreate a dataset quickly but it would filled based on the A-E values.  I think this should fix most of my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Subset your data in the individual `geom_text` call.

```r
ggplot(data=HIData, aes(x=factor(A,level=Ainorder),y=HQ)) +
  geom_col() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5, color = Listofcolors),axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0,vjust=0.5,color = "black")) + 
  ylab("HQ") + xlab("") + labs(title=paste0(first("HQ for "),HIData$ID)) + 
  aes(fill=Category) +
  geom_text(data=subset(HIData, HQ > 0), aes(label=HQ), angle=90) 
# Warning: Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
# Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.
```

[image]